# vespa: query/result.getContext(true).logValue(key,value) not working in accesslog

Tags: vespa

i want to add a custom key/value pair to the access log, as https://docs.vespa.ai/en/access-logging.html

test is

```
@Override
public HttpResponse handle(HttpRequest request) {
    Result result = null;
    try {
        String queryString = properties.getOrDefault("query", "");
        Query query = new Query("?query=" + encode(queryString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        query.getContext(true).logValue("this_is_key", "this_is_value");
        return response(query.toDetailString(), 200);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return response("Error handling search request", 400);
}
```

output: qrs/JsonAccessLog.container

`{"ip":"172.20.0.1","time":1625813285.167,"duration":0.011,"responsesize":61,"requestsize":0,"code":200,"method":"GET","uri":"/test/","version":"HTTP/1.1","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36","host":"localhost:8080","scheme":"http","localport":8080,"peeraddr":"172.20.0.1","peerport":42082}`

i can't find below element in the accss log

`"attributes": { "this_is_key": "this_is_value" }`

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The query context will only be populated to the access log in the context of a search handler. You may populate the attributes section from a request handler (e.g `ThreadedHttpRequestHandler`) through `request.getAccessLogEntry().get.().addKeyValue(key, value)`.